# RadioButton Selection in GridView

Tags: asp.net, gridview, radio-button, datalist

Here is my requirement.

I had 3 groups and having set of emplyees under each group.

So, I had placed 3 labels(To display groupname) 3 gridviews(to dispalay set of employees from each group) in a DataList. all the rows in 3 GridViews having RadioButtons.

Now problem is RadioButton is behaving like a checkbox, it is allowing multiple selections.

But, I need to select Only one RADIOBUTTON among all 3 Gridviews. How this can be acheived. Can Someone here help me?

```
/*********  Displaying Group Name and Its set of employes  **********/
```

/*********  This loop will execute 3 times as I had 3 groups.  **********/

```
protected void dlGraphItemDataBound(object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
{
    MyList dataitem = (MyList)e.Item.DataItem;

        if (dataitem != null)
        {
            Label lbl = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblMyLabel");
            lbl.Text = dataitem.GroupName;

            GridView dg = (GridView)e.Item.FindControl("gvList");

            if (dg != null)
            {
                List< MyList > groupItem = new List< MyList >(); // List of Employees

                foreach (MyList item in _empList)
                {
                    if (item.GroupName.Equals(dataitem.GroupName))
                 groupItem.Add(item); // Grouping all the emps who had same groupname
                }

             SetupReportGrid(dg); // Method to add controls to gridview dynamically
             dg.SetDataSource(groupItem); //Setting datasource for gridview
            }
        }
    }


protected void onRadioButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{           

        foreach (DataListItem dlItem in dlMyDataList.Items)
        {
            GridView grid = (GridView) dlItem.FindControl("gvList");
            if (grid != null)
            {
                RadioButton selectButton = (RadioButton) sender;
                GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow) selectButton.NamingContainer;

                int a = row.RowIndex;

                foreach (GridViewRow gridRow in grid.Rows)
                {
                    RadioButton rd = gridRow.FindControl("rdoSelect") as RadioButton;
                    if (rd.Checked)
                    {
                        if (gridRow.RowIndex == a)
                        {

                            rd.Checked = true;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            rd.Checked = false;
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

This is how i tried.... when i select first and second radiobutton in 1st gridview and after the event for 2nd radiobutton both 1st and 2nd radiobuttons got unchecked. As the loop executes for all gridviews and last grid having no radiobuttons checked. finally my code results as no radiobuttons checked

**Grid View Mark up:**

```
<asp:DataList ID="dlMyDataList" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="dlGraphItemDataBound">
                <ItemTemplate>                    
                    <table cellspacing="0" width="100%" >   

                        <tr>                                
                            <td nowrap="nowrap" width="100%" align="left" valign="middle">
                                <asp:Label ID="lblGroupName" runat="server" CssClass="ssrptsublabel" > </asp:Label>                                   
                            </td>
                         </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td width="100%" nowrap="nowrap" align="left" valign="middle">
                                 <asp:Panel id="pnlReport" runat="server" BorderWidth="0" Width="100%" Wrap="False">
                                    <commoncontrols:MyGridView id="gvList" runat="server" autogeneratecolumns="false" EnableViewState="True">
                                    </commoncontrols:MyGridViewview>
                                 </asp:Panel>                                     
                            </td>                                                        
                        </tr>  
                        </table>                                                      

                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:DataList>


**// Assigning controls dynamically to grid view
// Having Seperate customized class for gridview, based on that we are adding controls
//

GridViewColumnControl(ControlTypes, Control_ID, CSS Style, 0, databind,"" );**

private void SetupGrid(GridView grid)
    {

        IList<GridViewColumn> columns = new List<GridViewColumn>();

        GridViewColumn gridColumn = new GridViewColumn(ColumnTypes.TemplateColumn, "", 500, HorizontalAlign.Left,null);




       GridViewColumnControl control = new GridViewColumnControl(ControlTypes.RadioButton, "rdoSelect", "labelstyle", 0, null, "");
        control.Visible = false;
        control.AutoPostBack = true;
        control.OnChanged += onRadioButtonClicked;
        gridColumn.AddControl(control);



        control = new GridViewColumnControl(ControlTypes.DropDown, "", "style", 0, null, "");
        control.Visible = false;
        gridColumn.AddControl(control);




        grid.SetColumns(columns);
    }
```

Comment: I had placed the thr radiobutton portion for it.

Comment: First the groupname will be displayed. after that the grid with all employes of that group has to display.... Each row as radiobutton (with employee name) and associates dropdown

Answer (score 0):

The RadioButton control has a property called GroupName. All radio buttons having the same GroupName belong to the same group. In each radio button group only one radio button can be seleted. So I believe that if you set this property for all radio buttons in the grid views, you will fulfill your requirement.

Comment: Hi Ben, I tried Setting GroupName. But its not working. Still i can make multiple selections.

Comment: Another Issue added to this.... I have 4 rows in gridview having 1 radiobutton in each row.... Now if i seclecting 2nd radio button, its hitting oncheckedchange event and in sender i am getting all properties of this 2nd radiobutton.... Now problem is when i checked radiobutton second time. 2nd time i checked, radiobutton in 3rd row, and while oncheckedchage event hits, in sender i am still getting properties of 2nd row radiobutton. instead of actual radiobutton i clicked (3rd row)

Comment: Can you please add a code snippet that demonstrates these problems?